# Regular expression:same string different position different result

Tags: regex, bash

Requirements:
1. It must include at least one lowercase character [a-z]
2. It must include at least one digit \d
Here is my pattern  `\b(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b`.

```
match='\b(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b'
str1="12AAayuA 12345"
str2="12AAayuA 12345 12AAayuA 12345"
echo $str1 |grep -oP  $match
12AAayuA    
echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match
12AAayuA
12345
12AAayuA
```

Why the result of `echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match` is not the following?

```
12AAayuA
12AAayuA
```

With Anthony's regex expression : `\b(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b`,let it be $fixed-match.

```
echo $str2 |grep -oP  $fixed-match
12AAayuA
12AAayuA
```

My question still remain ,for my regex with a bug,
Why `12345` can be searched in `echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match` ,instead of `echo $str1 |grep -oP  $match`?
What is the working process for  `echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match`?
How `echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match` result in :

```
12AAayuA
12345
12AAayuA
```

not

```
12AAayuA
12AAayuA
```

and not

```
12AAayuA
12345
12AAayuA
12345
```

?

Comment: Are you trying to capture words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Understanding Lookahead

The reason is because you are misusing the lookahead windows.

When using lookahead windows, it only looks ahead. **it does not capture** So in summary, you aren't actually capturing anything when using the `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)` those are only validating the conditions ahead. The capturing is done with the `\b`,`\w`,`\b`. So with that in mind, let's reinterpret your regex.

It says look for a string that starts with a word boundary, then **verifies** the word boundary is followed by these conditions before proceeding... starting from here we verify there will **possibly** be a few non-lowercase number, **will** be a lowercase number, **possibly** a few non numerical, **will** be a numerical.

### Breakdown of Str1

Take `str1="12AAayuA 12345"` and start at `12345`,

It starts with a word boundary, good. but the `?=[^a-z]*[a-z]` lookahead is not satisfied because it does not end with a character.

### Breakdown of Str2

Now take `str2="12AAayuA 12345 12AAayuA 12345"` and start at `12345 12AAayuA 12345`

It starts with a word boundary, good. Now look ahead, the `?=[^a-z]*[a-z]` is satisfied because `12345 12AA` are not lower-case characters but the following character after `12345 12AA` is a lowercase character.

Now we move onto `(?=\D*\d)` But wait, lookahead window's look forward from the last expression which is **not** the lookback window but again it's the `\b`. So starting from `12345 12AAayuA 12345` we evaluate `(?=\D*\d)`, which is true

Now that the look aheads are dealth with we can capture. So starting from `12345 12AAayuA 12345` we capture the rest `\w+\b` which is why you get `12345`

### What is the correct solution?

I'd go with 
`\b(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*\d)\w*\b`

- Finds beginning of word
- Checks if word has lowercase
- Checks if word has number
- Then captures/matches

Comment: Anthony's regex is NOT equivalent to `\b(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*\d)\w*\b`. His `\b(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b` pattern is still flawed due to `\D*` that matches *any* char other than a digit, and will still overfire. `\w*` must be used in the lookaheads. But I'd use `\w+` in the consuming pattern.

Comment: If 2 regexp accept the exact same strings, then they are equivalent. If you can find an example where 1 regex accepts a string where another one rejects it, then that will prove they aren't equivalent. However, i can't think of a case where that would happen. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: The lookaheads ensure there will always be at least 2 characters in the string. Therefore, it doesn't really matter if you use `w*` or `w+`. At that point it's personal preference. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `\b(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b` matches `AAayuA` in `12AAayuA 12345 AAayuA 12345` while it should not ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/arJvhp/1/)). `\b(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*\d)\w*\b` [will correctly avoid matching it.](https://regex101.com/r/arJvhp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The character set [^a-z] in your look ahead assertion may be too permissive, as it also includes the spaces between words.

For emphasis you can try a test with the following:

```
\b(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)\w+\b
```

Comment: Your regex expression is correct,fix only one question ,but my other question is :with my bugged regex expression, Why 12345 can be searched in echo $str2 |grep -oP  $match ,instead of echo $str1 |grep -oP  $match?

Comment: 12345 is being matched because your look ahead assertion (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) is being satisfied for that word. Why is it being satisfied? It finds the transition from ^a-z to a-z *after* the word "12345". Your assertion is not restricted by the word boundary, and your assertion allows for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex regex that has few small flaws that impact the results in a big way. One flaw, as @Anthony mentions,

> The character set [^a-z] in your look ahead assertion may be too
>   permissive, as it also includes the spaces between words.

Let's take a step back and look at the requirements.

So you want a regex to validate a string with a lower case letter and a number.
Let's go over all of the possible ways that these 2 conditions can be met.
There are 2 formats where this can be true (**RA denotes random alphanumeric characters**):

- RA + lowercase + RA + number + RA  `(\w*[a-z]+\w*\d+\w*)`
- RA + number + RA + lowercase + RA  `(\w*\d+\w*[a-z]+\w*)`

Now we just have to combine these into one regex separated by a `|`.  It's a little long, but it gets the job done.

`\b(\w*[a-z]+\w*\d+\w*)|(\w*\d+\w*[a-z]+\w*)\b`

Comment: Your regex expression is as long as 45 characters,Anthony's is 34.

Comment: Just fyi your regex fails with `12AAayuA 12345 AAayuA 12345` as @WiktorStribiżew pointed out.